# Attaching a $(n+1)-$cell to $S^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I need to show that for any  $n,d \geq 1$ show there exists a space $X$ with $H_0(x) \cong  \mathbb{Z}, H_n(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$ and $H_q(X) \cong \{0\}$ if $q \neq 0,n.$

My idea is the attach a $(n+1)$-cell to $S^n$.

I'm not sure how to do it and if is this the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glue the cell along a map $\partial D^{n+1}\to S^n$ that represents $d\in \pi_n(S^n)\cong \Bbb Z$.

Comment: How do you get $ \mathbb{Z}/d$ ? Im confused. Can you give me more details

Comment: The point is that this cell has precisely the effect of killing $d \in \pi_n(S^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, so you end up quotienting by $d$.

Comment: By the [Hurewicz theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem), and the fact that the gluing gives $\pi_n(X)=\Bbb Z/d\Bbb Z$ directly.